# Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies in android-support-v7-appcompat

Tags: android, jar, android-support-library

In bin folder of library project "bin\android-support-v7-appcompat.jar" it is generates automatically and lib folder of library project "libs\android-support-v7-appcompat.jar" I put manually.

I got below error:

```
 Found 2 versions of android-support-v7-appcompat.jar in the dependency list,
but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).
All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.
Versions found are:
Path: D:\Market App\android_code_lib\android-support-v7-appcompat\bin\android-support-v7-appcompat.jar
Length: 166
    SHA-1: f61784cc598d88c31864ecc32c886b8f97f328a6
Path: D:\Market App\android_code_lib\android-support-v7-appcompat\libs\android-support-v7-appcompat.jar
    Length: 343731
    SHA-1: 3d62997c154488738d1367406fb7ac6074f992e2
Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
```

How to resolve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19989116/android-support-v7-appcombat-jar-mismatch-and-app-crashing-after-android-4-4-sdk?rq=1

Comment: @PankajKumar,  But in bin folder the jar file is generated automatically, so how to resolve this.

Comment: can you please specify which api version that you are used?

Comment: @JohnSMITH ,you just import your appcompact_v7 project to your project explorer and add jar file inside it to your android project.delete the jar file that you added earlier.

Comment: @JohnSMITH, I imported appcompact_v7.

Answer (score 2):

Expand your project and delete appcompatv7.jar from the "libs" folder. Clean your project and then run.
Using this method you are keeping one of the jars and removing the other due to which jar mismatch occurs.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the jar in the libs folder, and then clean and rebuild your project.  That worked for me!

Comment: I had tried using clean and rebuild the project, nut not works.

Comment: Did you delete the jar in the libs folder?  As long as you delete it and then clean and rebuild, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the lib file android-support-v4.jar from appcompact_v7 and past it to your project.

Answer (score 0):

please check that you have added support library jar file to your project properly.Please go through here [How to add support libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17891622/how-to-add-support-libraries)
 I have also the same situation and i rechecked the way that i am doing.The above link works for me......

Dont forget to clean and rebuild your project.